# Combining inline css and hover state, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I have found out that if we write inline css (or add it using JavaScript), then we lose the value of css hover. Is it possible to change such behavior?

**Simple example**

---

```
<div id="test" style="color: red">test</div>
<style>
#test:hover {
    color:blue;
}
</style>
```

In this case hover doesn't work.

**Update**

I can't use `!important`, because after it I will not be able to change that atribute via JavaScript.

Also I generate styles dynamically, so I can't add specific classes via JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I think your `style` elements should go in the `head` section.

Comment: That is not important ))

Answer (score 3):

because inline css overrides your css styles in the file
if you had

```
color: blue !important
```

it would work but not recommended, you can always use jquery to remove the inline style tag though haha

Update:

remove the style tag using jquery or when using javascript... add !important so the inline css would have important

Comment: css has a precedence over its selectors and direct css on the element takes precedence almost always

Comment: i can't use !important, because in this case i can't change the hover property after it(using javascript).

Comment: in javascript do ...mouseover = this.style.color = "blue";

Comment: Sure i can do it, but a'm wrining a large template customization application, and in that case i have to add huge count of code. I'm finding easier solution ))

Comment: well if you are writing templates then i don't see why you would have inline css at all

Comment: Inline css comes after i add styles using javascript.

Comment: hmm then i don't understand the whole conflict of css and javascript. it seems like you don't even need the css and use only js to change the hover. can you update the question with the ultimate goal. perhaps the approach can be changed

Comment: @Syom I don't recommend adding single styles, it is very hard to maintain, just create some classes and add/remove them as necessary (see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10642827/908879))

Answer (score 3):

> I can't use !important, because after it i will not be able to change
>   that atribute via javascript.

You can still use `!important`, just add a class with JavaScript and remove it anytime you want.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Thvq4/)

Comment: I'm geberating colors dynamically, using colorPicker, so i can't add classes.

Comment: @Syom consider adding that to your question so people don't waste their time writing an answer to later find this hidden comment after the harm is done

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to go is the following

```
$(selector).hover(function() {
                $st = $(this).attr("style");
                $(this).attr("style","");
            },function() {
                $(this).attr("style",$st);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, the `style` attribute will override any `style` elements or `stylesheets`. If you cannot change the the `style` attribute, you'll have to use `!important`. If you can remove the `style` attribute altogether and place everything in the `style` element. Or even better, in a separate `stylesheet` your problem will be fixed.

P.S. The `type` attribute is required on `style` elements. This won't fix your problem, but you should change `<style>` to `<style type="text/css">`